# Cakephp 3 multiple associations same model

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I'm building a game. For now I have 3 tables, 'games', 'users' and 'games_users'. For 'games' and 'users' I baked all files The association for 'games_users' works fine.

This are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
`userturn` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tag` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`status` int(1) NOT NULL,
`gametype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`won` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`facebook` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `games_users` (
`game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My associations for games_users:

In GamesTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'game_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinTable' => 'games_users'
]);
```

In UsersTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Games', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'game_id',
        'joinTable' => 'games_users'
]);
```

In the table 'games' there are two columns 'userturn' and 'won', they are both users_id's. How do i make the associations for those columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup multiple associations to Users table in Games table using different aliases for Users.

In `GamesTable`:

```
$this->belongsTo('UserTurn', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'userturn'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Won', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'won'
]);
```